# Error en vista tree Odoo 11

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Al realizar la vista Tree de mi modelo citas quiero que me aparezcan en la misma Fecha | Hora | Paciente(Nombre, Apellidos) Pero solo aparece Fecha | Hora | Paciente (Nombre). No entiendo porque, adjunto codigo de los modelos:

```
    class centromedico_pacientes(models.Model): #rw by secretaria users, r doctores/enfermeros
    _name = 'centromedico.pacientes'

    name = fields.Char(string="Nombre", required=True)
    apellidos = fields.Char(string="Apellidos", required=True)
    sexo = fields.Char(string="Sexo", required=True)

class centromedico_citas(models.Model): #rw by secretaria users, r doctores
    _name = 'centromedico.citas'

    fconsulta = fields.Date(string="Fecha consulta", required=True)
    hconsulta = fields.Float(string="Hora consulta", required=True)
    cpaciente = fields.Many2one('centromedico.pacientes', string="Paciente",required=True, ondelete="cascade")
```

Código de mi vista tree de citas:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="centromedico.citas_tree"> 
  <field name="name">centromedico.citas.tree</field>
  <field name="model">centromedico.citas</field> 
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree>
      <field name="fconsulta"/>
      <field name="hconsulta" widget="float_time"/>
      <field name="cpaciente">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="apellidos"/>
      </field>
    </tree>
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: cpaciente es un campo Many2one cuando lo llamas en la vista tree activa el metodo get_name que devuelve el campo name del modulo centromedico_pacientes, en este caso el campo name contiene solo el char Nombre no el Apellido.

Comment: Gabriel Asqui esa debió de ser respuesta y no comentario, saludos